# Persisting home component even when navigating away from it

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to persist an app's main 'home' component even when I'm navigating to another component? For example, in my app my home page points to `SelectTeamComponent` but every time I navigate to `SingleTeamComponent`, I lose `SelectTeamComponent`. I want this component to stay regardless of which page I'm on.

Here's the routing config I have in my `app.module` file

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SelectTeamComponent},
  { path: 'team/:id', component: SingleTeamComponent}
]
```

UPDATES Selected Team:

```
 onSelectedTeam(team){
    this.router.navigate(['/team', team.name]);
  }
```

SelectTeamComponent html:

```
<ul class="nav" *ngFor="let team of oneTeam">
        <li (click)="onSelectedTeam(team)" routerLinkActive="active">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="{{team.crest}}" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
            {{team.name}}
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

SingleTeam:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-team',
  templateUrl: './team.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team.component.css']
})

export class SingleTeamComponent implements OnInit {
  public teamID;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params)=>{
      let name = params['id'];
      this.teamID = id;
    })
  }
}
```

SingleTeam html:

```
<div class="content">
    <button class="primary btn">View last 5 games</button>
    <button class="primary btn">View all games this season</button> -->
  <app-last-game [nameOfTeam]="teamName"></app-last-game>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <app-last-five [nameOfTeam]="teamName"></app-last-five>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <app-head-to-head [nameOfTeam]="teamName"></app-head-to-head>
  </div>
  <app-all-games [nameOfTeam]="teamName"></app-all-games>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may add `SelectTeamComponent` as a parent component and add others as children,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
   component: SelectTeamComponent,
   children : [
    { path: 'team/:id', component: SingleTeamComponent} 
   ]
  }  
]
```

or move it to a named outlet.

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x0e6H7XQTQ0dP7YT82Ll?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Okay but this isn't letting me navigate to `SingleTeamComponent`

Comment: How are you navigating? How does your router link looks like?

Comment: I'm navigating through a `click` function on each sidebar item that triggers `this.router.navigate(['/team', team.id]);` in my sidebar component.

Comment: Can you show how does your SelectTeamComponent, html look like?

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: I don't see your html, its just the path, check the Plunker I have added.

Comment: I've updated with the html. Checking out your Plunker.

Comment: I've tried what you did in Plunker but the navigation doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update Plunker replicating your issue, in a minimal way possible?

Comment: I'm getting this error in console:
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'TeamComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'TeamComponent'`

Comment: Did you update `SelectTeamComponent` html to include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: Yes i have. Every time I click a link in SelectedTeamComponent, it throws that error.

Comment: Can you update Plunker replicating your issue, in a minimal way possible?

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to replicate because I'm getting data from an external API call that is being stored in an array of team objects.